# unique values from column with sql in R

Tags: sql-server, r

I need to extract unique values from a column in a table using sql in R.
Let's say I have a table called "alfa" and there is a column there called "SE".
SE has values that repeat themselves. I want to extract these values with a certain condition but each value only once and alphabetized , i.e

```
(rank , SE)
(5, guitar)
(3, coat)
(6, world)
(3, soap)
(5, soap)
(5, guitar)
(3, world )

dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT SE FROM alfa WHERE rank == 3")

SE
coat
soap
world
```

Comment: Don't know about SQL but once in R, you can do it with the apply family, unique() and sort().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `distinct` and `order by` keyword:

```
dbGetQuery(conn, "SELECT DISTINCT(SE) FROM alfa WHERE rank = 3 ORDER BY SE")
```

Comment: @TheGameiswar I tested on MySQL and It should work on SQL as well. Other databases, I am not sure.